# Tinymce in .Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i am creating a webform in .net 2010. I have ajax control tool kit in .net.
 Now i want to know is there any way to create a tinymce like rich editor in .net. 
Is any tinymce extender exist in ajax control toolkit.

Please suggest me some

Answer (score 2):

In the `head` part of your page:

```
document.onload = function() 
{  
   tinyMCE.init({elements : "<%=txtContent.ClientID %>"} );
};
```

Also, you can use some ready to use server controls:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8141
http://tinymce.codeplex.com/